# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, flask, syntax-error

When I try to debug `Hello Flask` in VisualStudio I get this error:

> **UnicodeDecodeError**: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0: invalid continuation byte

I am using Python 3.4, VisualStudio Community with Python Tools. This is the full log:

```
The Python REPL process has exited
 * Running on http://localhost:5555/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FlaskFirstTest \FlaskFirstTest\app.py", line 24, in <module>
app.run(HOST, PORT)
File "c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FlaskFirstTest\FlaskFirstTest\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 772, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FlaskFirstTest\FlaskFirstTest\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 625, in run_simple
inner()
File "c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FlaskFirstTest\FlaskFirstTest\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 603, in inner passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()
File "c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FlaskFirstTest\FlaskFirstTest\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 512, in make_server
passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
File "c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FlaskFirstTest\FlaskFirstTest\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 440, in __init__
HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 429, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 135, in server_bind
self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 460, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I would like to know what is causing this error.

Comment: Is the string in `name` a Unicode String?
You should use `encode()` to encode the string.
`name.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')`

Comment: @Vaulstein: this is in Werkzeug; the hostname contains non-ascii characters..

Comment: It's a blank application in VS and I don't touch anything, just try to debug for test and reach this message during course session on MVA